# Eclipse export to a runnable JAR - Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for :

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I try to export to a runnable JAR.

But it is not working.

the error I get is

```
Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 'ChatC/src/Command_Manager.java'
```

My program source code is github.

https://github.com/egaoneko/Po_Tweeter_Client

https://github.com/egaoneko/Po_Tweeter_Server

Answer (score 1):

Usually caused by having completely empty classes in your project (or one of its dependencies). Just take a look at the source (.java) files of those 'not found or not accessible' classes that appear in the log...